# How can I run cucumber test scenarios in parallel in Local machine?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, cucumber

Currently using a test runner with tags and I want to run multiple scenarios parallel in the local machine. How can I achieve it?

```
-ea -Dcucumber.options="--tags @myTest"
```

Comment: If you're using JUnit 5, you toggle a few properties. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine You can use this as a starting base https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/